# Problem with Set Attribute after migration from Magento 1.9.4.3 to 2.3.3 via Data Migration Tool

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, data-migration, data-migration-tool

The data migration has ended successfully.
The only problem is when I switch the product attribute set from the default magento 2 to a custom one.

Error:
"**A technical problem with the server created an error. Try again to continue what you were doing. If the problem persists, try again later.**"

The theme I use is Porto.